# Access VBA Internet Explorer automation MS Edge object disappearing

Tags: vba, ms-access, automation, internet-explorer-11

I"m working on a scraping solution on a Windows 10 box using Access 2010 32 bit.
Problem is that the IE object is somehow reset to Nothing during execution (error generated on line 17 of below snippet).
When running the code step by step it seems to work. 
When visually inspecting the Explorer window it looks like expected.
What am I doing wrong here ? Any ideas / suggestions highly appreciated.

```
Public Function politseiKontroll(dokument As String) As String
Dim ie As Object
Dim element As Object
Dim filenum
Const URL As String = "https://www.politsei.ee/et/teenused/e-paringud/dokumendi-kehtivuse-kontroll/"
Const SIGNATURE = MODULE_NAME & "politseiKontroll"
On Error GoTo ERR_

If Len(Trim(dokument)) = 0 Or Len(Trim(dokument)) > 20 Then
   politseiKontroll = "Number on liiga pikk (20 max)"
   Exit Function
End If
1 Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
2 ie.visible = True
' 2 Prevents the URL from being added to the history list
' 4 Prevents the browser from reading the page from the disk cache
' 8 Prevents the URL from being added to the disk cache
3 ie.Navigate URL, 2 + 4 + 8    ' prevent using page from local cache
4 While ie.Busy And ie.ReadyState <> 4 ' READYSTATE_COMPLETE
5   DoEvents
6 Wend
7 If ie.Document Is Nothing Then
    ie.Quit
8    Set ie = Nothing
9    politseiKontroll = "Serveri vastus puudub"
10 End If
11 Set element = ie.Document.getElementsByName("docNumber")
12 If element.length <> 1 Then
13        ie.Quit
14     Set ie = Nothing
15     politseiKontroll = "Serveri vastuse formaat on vale"
16 End If
17 ie.Document.getElementsByName("docNumber")(0).value = dokument
While ie.Busy And ie.ReadyState <> 4 ' READYSTATE_COMPLETE
  DoEvents
Wend
18 Set element = ie.Document.getElementsByName("subButton")
19 If element.length <> 1 Then
20    ie.Quit
21    Set ie = Nothing
22    politseiKontroll = "Serveri vastuse formaat on vale"
23 End If
24 ie.Document.getElementsByName("subButton")(0).Click
25 While ie.Busy And ie.ReadyState <> 4
26   DoEvents
27 Wend
28    Stop
29    ie.Quit
30 Set ie = Nothing
31 DoEvents

EXIT_:
32    Exit Function
ERR_:
'    Dim eClone As New errClone
'    eClone.init err, , erl
    If Not ie Is Nothing Then
        ie.Quit
        Set ie = Nothing
        DoEvents
    End If
'    Set eClone = errorHandler.reportError(eClone, SIGNATURE)
'    If eClone.stopExecution Then
        Stop
'    End If
    Resume EXIT_
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

It you quit IE, you shouldn't use the object later, so:

```
12 If element.length <> 1 Then
13        ie.Quit
14     Set ie = Nothing
15     politseiKontroll = "Serveri vastuse formaat on vale"
16 End If

If Not ie Is Nothing Then
    ie.Document.getElementsByName("docNumber")(0).value = dokument
    While ie.Busy And ie.ReadyState <> 4 ' READYSTATE_COMPLETE
        DoEvents
    Wend
<snip>
```